# React Native local image path from API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flask, react-redux

I am starting to learn React Native and I have build an API with flask that simply returns a string to where an image would be in the asset folder. For instance

```
data {
   path : "../assets/image.jpg"
}
```

The Flask API returns that path that is in the React-Native actual local directory. However, after getting this data, I can't put in in an image like normal. When I try

```
<Image source={require(path)} />
```

It says Its incorrect. I did not show the full code here but I am correctly getting the API data as well as formatting the  as putting `source={require("../assets/path")}` works.

Answer (score 0):

we cannot dynamic import in react native

you can use this approch

```
const allPaths = {
  path1: require('../assets/image1.jpg'),
  path2: require('../assets/image2.jpg')
};
```

And then you use it somehow like:

```
<Image source={allPaths["path1"]} />
```

Comment: Thats a brilliant idea and I though it would work, the only problem is, when i try that it say "allPaths" is not a function. allPaths is an instance of Object

Comment: I have updated my answer. @NathanBelete now you can check